# jQuery top, bottom or both?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a simple website utilizing Bootstrap 3 framework, with a couple of items requiring jQuery, I understand that the jQuery is at the base of the page (via CDN) and I understand the reasons for this but on the tutorial I am watching at the moment it is requiring the jQuery to be placed in the head, I cant see the need to call this twice or am I just plain WRONG.

Comment: No need to call twice. Head or bottom is just two different paradigms. Earlier Google advocated head but has since changed to bottom. Be happy and move on... :)

Comment: doesn't matter where, loading order is what's important

Comment: you can put your scripts at the end of the page so that the actual html can be seen while the scripts are loaded, otherwise you have to look at  blank page while they load

Answer (score 0):

It's preferred to put the scripts at the bottom just before the closing `</body>` tag, for example Google [suggests this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview#trackingCodePlacement) for their analytics scripts:

> By placing the script at the end of the page body, you ensure that the tracking code is executed as the last element of the DOM. If a given page load is interrupted for some reason, it is possible that the GIF request for that page view will not be executed. However, should you place the tracking code at the top of the page, any load interruptions might result in incomplete or inaccurate reporting anyhow, since the tracking code relies on page data for its reports.

So that the rest of the page doesn't have to wait for these scripts to load. However, if you notice flickering or you notice that your page's HTML markup looks strange and needs the jquery as soon as possible, you should definitely move it to the `<head>` portion of your page. (And don't place the script twice, only at the top or only at the bottom!)